# Performant check whether a directory contains at least n files

Tags: python, performance, counter, os.walk, listdir

I a script that processes files from a folder calles `source`. As I process these files in batches I need to verify that at least `n` files are in `source`. The problem is that `source` possibly contains a few hundred thousand or millions of files, thus `len(os.listdir(src))` is too slow for my needs.

I've considered having a function that `os.walk`s in `source` until the number if minimum required files reached, then returns `True`, else `False`. I just tested walk really quick

```
for rwalk,dwalk,fwalk in os.walk(C:\\tmp\\folder\\):
    for f in fwalk: 
        print(f)
```

which blurts out in tons of information even if `C:\\tmp\\folder\\` only contains a handful of files.

How can I have a function that checks if at least `n` files are in `source` without *listing* every contained file first?

Comment: Python does not (yet) have a streaming version of `os.listdir()`. That method returns a list of all entries, always.

Comment: That is what I understood from reading the `os.listdir()` documentation, but does `os.walk()` do the same? Is there no other achieve a one-after-the-other file counter?

Comment: All other directory listing / walking code uses `os.listdir()` under the hood.